# How would I make a custom tilemap, from an image that contains where the borders of each tile should be?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

Think like Europa Universalis IV or Crusader Kings 3. I know that sorta stuff is hand drawn, so there must be a file, that basically tells engine where the borders of each tile should be.

And actually there is an image in the EUIV files that's basically the whole map with each tile, all of them just colored in a different color.

Anybody knows of resources, videos, blog posts that could help me figure it out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the tilemap in the Unity, you can use the Rule tiles, which are scriptable tiles, that can detect whether another tile is placed next to specific side of the tile. Then depending on the rules you have set up, it will create different tile.

This page explains the idea, as well as there are many tutorials how to implement them.

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/using-rule-tiles#